# Interactive mapping with Matplotlib and Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, jupyter-notebook

I'm not so much experienced with Python and Matplotlib and ipywidgets. I'm trying to build a jupyter interactive notebook that shows a map and then overplots different marine isobtahs (lines of constant depths). I would like to show/hide some lines with the help of an array of checkboxes. The problem is trying to redraw the map once some lines are selected. So the strategy is
schematically:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from ipywidgets import *  
from IPython.display import display

load_map() # loads isobaths from files (arrays of lat,lon pairs)

def draw_mapa(): #draw the map
    mapa = Basemap()
    mapa.drawcoastlines()

def draw_level(level): #draw a specific line (z=level)
    mapa.plot(x,y)

def on_level_change(change): #handler of checkboxes
    draw_mapa()
    if button is True:
       draw_level(level)

display(container) #container with all the checkboxes

  #attaching handler to checkbox through .observe() method
for ilevel in checkboxes:
     ilevel.observe(on_level_change,names='value')
```

Everything is ok except when I start to interact with the checkboxes. Each time I select/deselect a box a new additonal map with the corrected isobaths appears.

So the question is how is the way to "overplot" correctly in one figure avoiding creating new instances each time I check a box.

Thanks

Comment: This is going to be very cumbersome and hard with `matplotlib`, not that it's impossible. You're better off with [`bokeh`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, and I did not explore in detail but, I did'n see in the bokeh documentation the support for mapping features as many basemap methods (projections, contour and plotting vectors, etc..) which is particularly interesting for my project.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not well documented as the other features in `bokeh`, but this link might help. http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html#userguide-geo

Comment: It might take you some while to get the features working to however you might like them, but in the long run it'll be much easier than doing that in mpl/basemap.